# Multiple attribute form views in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, widget

In QGIS 3.18. There are 3 ways of visualizing attribute information that I am aware of:

1. The attribute table
2. the Identify Features box
3. the Form view (accessible via either the attribute table or the Identify Features box).

Changing the settings in Layer Properties-->Attributes Form determines the visualization settings for all of the above, with only minor exceptions (for example, fields set to "Hidden" in Widget Type will still be visible in the normal view of the Attribute Table, but other Widget types will in fact change the field's appearance there).

If the above is correct, my question is the following:

Is there any way of **switching back and forth between full view** (the default view with all fields visible and no widgets or constraints active) **and the designed view** (with widgets, constraints, and hidden fields)?

If this is allowed by any of the 3 views above, or by a plugin, or by an existing code that can be easily executed, I am unaware of it, but it would be very helpful for data entry *situations where 95% of the data will occur in only just a few fields* ('designed view') but the occasional 5% may necessitate access to the full view with all fields.

(Note: I have 100+ fields so I'd rather not go back to Attributes Form and unhide each field I need one by one.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have two tabs, one with just a few fields and the other one with all of them. Select the fields to be part of a tab and move them over the "tab" entry (not just below)

[image]

[image]

Note that when the attribute table is opened, you can switch between `form view` and `table view` by clicking on the lower right icons

[image]

Comment: Excellent trick, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @JGH!

Comment: Not sure if this falls within the same question or should be posted separately, but it seems that while this feature does allow viewing different 'sets' of fields (tabs), the manner in which they are viewed (widgets, constraints, aliases) is not different for each set. For example, if I give a field an alias with a longer name, this alias will be the title for that field in all forms and in the attribute table. This may be rather inconvenient. Is it possible to associate different settings with different sets/tabs for specific views?

Comment: @pete I don't know, please ask a new question for this so it can attract more people